# haproxy domain routing

Tags: web-server, load-balancing, haproxy, socket

I am trying to set up haproxy to route to backends depending on the the subdomain that was used in the http request. Eg I have a regular web server running on port 8000 and an application server waiting for websocket connections running on port 8001 on the same IP adress. I now want that if the user hits app.mydomain.com:80 that he is redirected to port 8001 and if he hits www.mydomain.com (or any other subdomain) that he is redirected to the webserver on port 8000.

I came up with a plain configuration that I think should accomplish that (it is based loosly on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419346/can-nginx-be-used-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-a-backend-websocket-server)):

```
frontend all 0.0.0.0:80
  timeout client    86400000
  acl aclMS1 hdr_dom(host) -i app
  use_backend   beMS1   if aclMS1
  default_backend   beWEB

backend beMS1
  timeout server 86400000
  server srvMS1 localhost:8001 maxconn 200 check

backend beWEB
  server webserver localhost:8000 maxconn 200 check
```

However, it seems like this does not work. I always end up at my webserver on port 8000. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get it working. I was missing the mode http option. My config now looks like this and works like a charm:

```
defaults
  mode http
  timeout server 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms

frontend all 0.0.0.0:80
  timeout client    86400000
  acl aclMS1 hdr_dom(host) -i app
  use_backend   beMS1   if aclMS1
  default_backend   beWEB

backend beMS1
  timeout server 86400000
  server srvMS1 localhost:8001 maxconn 200 check

backend beWEB
  server webserver localhost:8000 maxconn 200 check
```